# How to get permanent link after publishing posts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can I get the permanent link dynamically, after publishing the posts in Wordpress. I would like to send the permanent link privately into an API 
after publishing the post.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
add_action('transition_post_status', 'send_new_post', 10, 3);

function send_new_post($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
  if('publish' === $new_status && 'publish' !== $old_status && $post->post_type === 'post') {
    print(get_post_permalink($post));
  }
}
```

You're using the post status transition hook to detect when a post is being publish. And then grabbing the permalink.

Source for post publish hook: https://davidwalsh.name/wordpress-publish-post-hook